# Laravel Framework 5.7.29 blank main page

Tags: laravel, xampp

I was having problems with a blank page in my first Laravel project. I'm currently watching the Laravel Framework course on YouTube. This is Lesson 1 called "How to install the Laravel Framework". I checked it out laravel.com for the requirements section and made sure I have all of them. After that, I installed Composer 2.0.13. Using it, I installed Laravel Framework 5.7.29. I got reports that some packages are deprecated. They were about changing the color on the console.
The next step was to change "/etc/hosts". I added the line `127.0.0.1 poligon.local` The next step was to change "/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf". I added the lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/stas/projects/poligon.local/public"
    ServerName poligon.local
    ServerAlias www.poligon.local
    
    <Directory /home/stas/projects/poligon.local/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "logs/poligon-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/poligon-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I wrote `$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` to start the local XAMPP server. And I have a blank page on the "poligon.local/". When I started `php artisan serve`, I had access to "poligon.local:8000", and there is the Laravel home page. But the author of the video got access to the "poligon.local" without `php artisan serve`. What do you think is my mistake?

Update: If I create /public/index.html I will get this html page.

Update2: I was experimenting now with `php artisan serve --host 127.0.0.1 --port 80` and found that with the XAMPP server enabled, this socket is already in use. But when the server is turned off, I manage to run artisan command with these connection settings. As I understand it, XAMPP occupies this socket, but for some reason can't handle it on its own.

Update3: I checked it out /public/index.php the whole file and found out that it is being executed. Up to the line `$response = $kernel->handle( $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture() );` There is no continuation after it.

Comment: Nothing in Laravel's log file? Any specific reason to install an old version and not go with the latest Laravel 8?

Comment: @brombeer The logs are clean, except that I accidentally wrote ```server``` instead of ```serve```. I installed the latest version, but after a dozen lessons, it became difficult to track changes in the versions.

Answer (score 0):

Define the site you added in `hosts` file in the Virtual Host route.

Change this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/stas/projects/poligon.local/public"
    ServerName poligon.local
    ServerAlias www.poligon.local
    
    <Directory /home/stas/projects/poligon.local/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "logs/poligon-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/poligon-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

to this

```
<VirtualHost poligon.local:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/stas/projects/poligon.local/public"
    ServerName poligon.local
    ServerAlias www.poligon.local
    
    <Directory /home/stas/projects/poligon.local/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "logs/poligon-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/poligon-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Notice that i have defined the host URL you defined in the virtual host route

From `<VirtualHost *:80>` to the url you defined `<VirtualHost poligon.local:80>`

What this `*` does is it gets all the requests and direct it to XAMPP homepage which is default.

Comment: It is a good try. But it does not work. I updated topic.

Comment: It is after this change that the page is redirected to the "XAMPP home page".

Comment: Oops. I did a mistake. I wrote <VirtualHost poligon.local*:80>. And this line redirect me to "XAMPP home page". With <VirtualHost poligon.local:80> it is a blank bage again.

Comment: Did you restart your XAMPP server after configuring @stas12go ? Try to free the port and re-check

Comment: Can you add the path in inverted commas `<Directory "/home/stas/projects/poligon.local/public">` and check once again ?